# Facebook Api post on behave of the user ( via tag )

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I got the following question. When I place a status message for an user, I would like to add my Facebook page as reference. I have seen other posts where the tag "via" is placed under the capitation. 
How do I achieve that?
I am using the C# SDK from Facebook.  I am already able to post with the following code:

```
FacebookClient fbClient = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
var args = new Dictionary<string, object>();                
args["place"] = objectFBID;             
fbClient.Post("/me/feed", args);
```

What parameter is needed for the "via" tag. I tried the "from" parameter, however it didn't work!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When posting on a wall, make sure the user has given the right permissions to the App. Otherwise alot of data is hidden. This was the case with my facebook account. When using a facebook account that has given full acces, all data is displayed.